# Need to Print unique combinations of numbers from an array when elements are repeated

Tags: java

I need to write a Program,where i will Print unique combinations of numbers from an array.
Example:
Input is {1,2,1}
output should be :121,112,211
I have tried below code but it returns just 1 combination.
Also it should be std input.

---

```
 import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;

class Main
{
     static void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, 
                                int end, int index, int r) 
    { 
        // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it 
        if (index == r) 
        { 
            for (int j=0; j<r; j++) 
                System.out.print(data[j]+" "); 
            System.out.println(""); 
            return; 
        } 
   
        for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++) 
        { 
            data[index] = arr[i]; 
            combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r); 
        } 
    } 
  
    static void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r) 
    { 
   
        int data[]=new int[r]; 
  
        combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r); 
    } 
 
    public static void main (String[] args) {  
int r=3;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        int arr[] = new int[num];

        System.out.println("Enter the " + num + " numbers now.");

        for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
            arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        input.close(); 
        int n = arr.length; 
        printCombination(arr, n, r); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's not a home work question.

Comment: I see you declare `r` but don't initialize it. Not sure if that's intentional, but pretty sure it's part of the reason for the behaviour you're seeing. Also, you `return` from `combinationUtil()` after printing the current combination. Considering that you pass `index` as 0 to the method, and `r` is by default initialized to 0 but never modified, then the code is doing exactly what it's meant to do: print the current combination.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper , yes i have intialize r to 3 now but still same result :(

Comment: You can always compare your code with [the source from where you seem to have taken it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/). If the behaviour is different, then clearly there's a difference in the code. Or in the input you're using, and that affects the behaviour of the code. Run both through a debugger step by step and see where they differ.

Answer (score 0):

This task calls **permutation**. You need to find all *permutations* of the given numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(permute(1, 2, 1));   // [[2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
}

public static Set<String> permute(int... nums) {
    if (nums == null || nums.length == 0)
        return Collections.emptySet();

    Arrays.sort(nums);
    return permute(new HashSet<>(), nums, -1);
}

private static Set<String> permute(Set<String> res, int[] nums, int j) {
    j++;

    if (j == nums.length - 1)
        res.add(Arrays.toString(nums));
    else {
        for (int i = j; i < nums.length; i++) {
            swap(nums, j, i);
            permute(res, nums, j);
            swap(nums, j, i);
        }
    }

    return res;
}

private static void swap(int[] nums, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = nums[i];
    nums[i] = nums[j];
    nums[j] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense , will try it out.